# showing all conversation between two users php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display the conversation between two users and I have view.php where I show the message and I also have reply button on that page. I am lost on how to insert the data to existing message row and show all the conversation. Thanks for any help.

My table structure:

```
         id
         from_user
         to_user
         deleted
         message
         date
```

view.php

```
 $user = 'currentuser';
 $reply = $_POST['relpy'];
 $id = $_GET['id']; 
 if (isset($_POST['replyto']))
 $reply = $_POST['reply'];  {
 if(!empty($reply)){



 $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');//this is where I am stuck I am using update so if I hit reply the existing data in the row will be overwritten.
 $stmt = $mydb->prepare("update  messages set message = ? where from_user = ?  and id = ? ");
 echo $mydb->error;
 $stmt->bind_param('sss', $reply, $user, $id);

$stmt->execute();


}
}
 if(!empty($id)){
 $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
 $stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages where from_user = ?   and id = ? ");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $id);
 $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you want **NOT** to insert an another row between these users/conversation, but update the current row (message field) with its old value plus the new.

IMHO this is a bad implementation with extra work on data handling, but you can do it if you change your update query to:

> update messages set message = concat(message, ?) where from_user = ? and id = ?

Comment: yeah that is what I wanted but is there a better way?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that you have already a table for your members/users, you can create a table for messages. In that table, you can store some basic data of a message like its Id, the content and the date. Finally you should create an another table named conversation, which is the mapper between users and messages. Work with relations.